# How to prevent whereRaw from automatically sort my collection?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have a list of ids which are id of a collection after sorted, e.g:

```
$orderedIds = "2,18,4,1,17,5,6,16,15,14,13,11,12,10,9,8,7,3"
```

and I want to pick them out with `whereRaw` like this:

```
$result = Collection::whereRaw("FIELD(id, ".$orderedIds." )");
```

but the result is automatically sorted by id, which means the collection output is literally the original collection:

```
[
 {
   "id": 1,
   ...
 }, {
   "id": 2,
   ...
 }, {
   "id": 3,
   ...
 }
]
```

Any option with `whereRaw`, or any other way around for me to achieve the sorted collection?

Comment: Why not use the `whereIn` option in laravel ?
https://www.tutorialsplane.com/laravel-where-in/

Comment: If the values in the collection are already ordered before the where, doing a whereRaw() would still give you a ordered collection.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 Collection::whereIn('id',$orderedId)->orderByRaw(DB::raw("FIELD(id, $orderedId)"))->get();
```